# ALTER DB error when the connection string has an instance name - C# 4.0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a service written in C# that runs under the domain admin account.  This account is set as SQL admin on all the SQL Servers in that domain.  The service needs to copy a mdf/ldf (SQL server 2003 or 2008) from one server to another and attach it to the new server.  Instead of detaching the DB at the source server, I am changing the DB status to read only, and then copying the mdf/ldf files.  Once they get copied over, I reset the DB status to read-write.

This is working if the source server name is something like MYSQLSERVER2K8.  However, the code does not work if it is an instance name.  For example: MYSQLSERVER2K8\VAULT.  I have run the unit tests in NUnit on my code and the unit tests pass for both cases.  However, the service is unable to change the DB status.  The error we get is as follows:

> SQL: ALTER DATABASE My_Test_DataBase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Database 'My_Test_DataBase' does not exist. Check sysdatabases. ALTER DATABASE statement failed. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.

Here is my code (note that I am converting the server name to the IP address in the connection string.  For example: MYSQLSERVER2K8\VAULT gets converted to 111.111.111.111\VAULT:

```
#region ChangeDatabaseStatus
    /// <summary>
    /// Change the database status to read-only/read-write
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverName"></param>
    /// <param name="databaseName"></param>
    /// <param name="status"></param>
    public virtual bool ChangeDatabaseStatus(string serverName, string databaseName, string status)
    {
        DateTime beginTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        string sql = String.Empty;
        bool databaseStatusChanged = false;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection(false);

            string connectionString = connection.ConnectionString;
            string serverIPAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(serverName.Contains(@"\") ? serverName.Substring(0, serverName.IndexOf(@"\")) : serverName)[0].ToString();
            connectionString = connectionString.Replace("{0}", serverIPAddress = serverName.Contains(@"\") ? serverIPAddress + serverName.Substring(serverName.IndexOf(@"\"), serverName.Length - serverName.IndexOf(@"\")) : serverIPAddress);

            connection.Close();
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);                

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandTimeout = _commandTimeout;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                command.CommandText = String.Format("ALTER DATABASE {0} SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", databaseName);

                //Debugging & Exception handling
                sql = HelperFunctions.BuildSQL(command);

                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();
            }

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandTimeout = _commandTimeout;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                command.CommandText = status == "ReadOnly" ? String.Format("ALTER DATABASE {0} SET READ_ONLY", databaseName) : String.Format("ALTER DATABASE {0} SET READ_WRITE", databaseName);

                //Debugging & Exception handling
                sql = HelperFunctions.BuildSQL(command);

                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();

                databaseStatusChanged = true;
            }

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandTimeout = _commandTimeout;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                command.CommandText = String.Format("ALTER DATABASE {0} SET MULTI_USER", databaseName);

                //Debugging & Exception handling
                sql = HelperFunctions.BuildSQL(command);

                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new DataProviderException(String.Format("{0} operation failed. SQL: {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, sql), e);
        }
        finally
        {

            LogPerformance(String.Format("Elapsed time for: {0}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name), beginTimeStamp, DateTime.Now, null);
        }

        return databaseStatusChanged;
    }
    #endregion //ChangeDatabaseStatus
```

Comment: Erm why are you converting it to an ip? My instant reaction was there's your problem....

Comment: Would that be an issue?  So in web.config, connectionString ="data source=<IP Address>\VAULT;...", that would cause it?  Because, when I run this in our dev/testing environment, it works if connectionString = "data source=<IP Address>;...";

Comment: The reason we convert to IP address is because for whatever reason, our dev/test server is unable to do the DNS lookup for any server name (example: MYSQLSERVER2K8).  It works if you supply it the IP address.  I will try by not converting to the IP address and see if that works.  Hopefully, the DNS lookup issue is fixed on that server now.

Comment: I tried without using the IP address.  hence, with MYSQLSERVER2K8\VAULT but it still fails.  :-/

Comment: DNS lookup can't be relied upon it should be using the sqlbrowser service for connections. IT's possible for the machine names the instance installed to be different from the servber name of teh instance.. Can you connect with sql server manager osql, something from source machine to target?

Comment: I did a trace on the SQL Server and found it was connecting to the wrong instance: MYSQLSERVER2K8 and not MYSQLSERVER2K8\VAULT.  Debugging and finding out why the instance name is being stripped from the connection string.  I'm not using the IP address any longer.  Thanks for the suggestions.  This should be sorted out soon.  Enjoy your weekend.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check you don't have an alias configured.

Load the Sql Server Configuration Manager, under Native Client, then Aliases.

As Tony Hopkinson says, test you can connect using sqlcmd or something from the same machine:

```
sqlcmd -S MYSQLSERVER2K8\VAULT -q "ALTER DATABASE dbname SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
```